# Simple Button Hide on Click

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Hello I'm obviously not too experienced with tkinter very much and I couldnt find anything on what *I* was looking for, maybe someone could help me

```
def hide(x):
    x.pack_forget()

d=Button(root, text="Click to hide me!" command=hide(d))
d.pack()
```

I would like it so that on click the command runs but the button is not defined when calling the command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not use anything if you are still building. Must you use `configure` and `lambda` function:

```
from tkinter import *

def hide(x):
    x.pack_forget()

root = Tk() 
d=Button(root, text="Click to hide me!")

d.configure(command=lambda: hide(d))
d.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: This  isn't quite right. There's no need to use `configure` in this case.

Comment: Why do you say that, explain yourself?

Comment: My mistake. I didn't see that you are passing the same widget reference to the command.

Comment: Thanks for the help :)

Comment: @JamesFitzy If my answer helps, mark it as correct please

Answer (score 1):

First, define the button, then add the command with the `config` method.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
def hide(x):
    x.pack_forget()

d=Button(root, text="Click to hide me!")
d.pack()
d.config(command=lambda: hide(d))

root.mainloop()
```